# How do I get the content of a <span> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the content 'This is my name' of the span?

```
<div id='item1'>
<span>This is my name</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 326, accepted):

I think this should be a simple example:

```
$('#item1 span').text();
```

or

```
$('#item1 span').html();
```

Comment: Where do I find those jQuery functions?

Comment: I think it's important when showing these two functions that we don't confuse new coders by suggesting that they do the same thing, when they do not (although in this example it will appear so). It is important to note that `.text()` will html encode any characters it finds, while `.html()` will not encode any characters.

Comment: Can this be accomplished with multiple spans with the same class?

Comment: I stumbled across this trying to figure out tspan to work with IE. I have found that you need to use .text() with tspan and not .html(). Unsure why and it may not be the case for everyone but it fixed it in IE when I used .text().

Comment: @MatthewWoodard `$('.class').each(function() { $(this).html() });`; because `$('.class').html()` will return the .html() value for the first element

Comment: Should also be noted that if this is not directly on a span and you call `text()` that it will traverse all subnodes and concat the result

Answer (score 15):

```
$("#item1 span").text();
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you intended it to read id="item1", you need

```
$('#item1 span').text()
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use id in span directly in your html.

```
<span id="span_id">Client</span>
```

Then your jQuery code would be

```
$("#span_id").text();
```

Some one helped me to check errors and found that he used val() instead of text(), it is not possible to use val() function in span.
So

```
$("#span_id").val();
```

will return null.

Answer (score 5):

Since you did not provide an attribute for the 'item' value, I am assuming a class is being used:

```
<div class='item1'>
  <span>This is my name</span>
</div>

alert($(".item span").text());
```

Make sure you wait for the DOM to load to use your code, in jQuery you use the `ready()` function for that:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>jQuery test</title>
  <!-- script that inserts jquery goes here -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() { alert($(".item span").text()); });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='item1'>
   <span>This is my name</span>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you've changed the question! Your answer is right for your question,  he was specifying the id not a class name

Comment: well, if you see the first comment under his name you will notice that he did not write an attribute at all, it was <div 'item1'>, I guessed wrong apparently.

Answer (score 5):

`$('#item1').text(); or $('#item1').html();` works fine for `id="item1"`

Answer (score 3):

In javascript wouldn't you use `document.getElementById('item1').innertext`?

Answer (score 1):

```
     $('span id').text(); worked with me
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#id span').text()` is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

`$('#item1 span').html();` Its working with my code

Answer (score 0):

VERY IMPORTANT Additional info on difference between .text() and .html():

If your selector selects more than one item, e.g you have two spans like so
`<span class="foo">bar1</span>`
`<span class="foo">bar2</span>`
,

then

`$('.foo').text();` appends the two texts and give you that; whereas

`$('.foo').html();` gives you only one of those.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $.each($(".classBalence").find("span"), function () {
            if ($(this).text() >1) {
                $(this).css("color", "green")

            }
            if ($(this).text() < 1) {
                $(this).css("color", "red")
                $(this).css("font-weight", "bold")
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
```