# Jquery traverse using prev() failed in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to get the value of `.itemLink` when I click on the `.card`

```
var item = $('.card');

item.on('click',function() {
    if ($(this).next('.content').is(':empty')) {
        alert($(this).prev('.card').find('.itemLink').val());
    }
}
```

I got an undefined?

my DOM

[image: DOM Image]

Comment: `val()` is for form elements, you need the `.html()` function

Comment: @Clyde I need val() for <span>getthevaluehere</span>?

Comment: no one can provide the answer here?

Comment: [Duplicate] This has been asked before: "*[How do I get a value of a <span> using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921342/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-a-span-using-jquery)*"

Comment: I have already provided the answer in the comment. Here is a fiddle to clarify your doubt http://jsfiddle.net/b22hnyyh/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the alert, you should have:

```
$(this).find('.itemLink').html()
```

You're clicking on `.card`, which is the parent element already, so the `.prev('.card')` part that you have is incorrect, as is using `.val()` on a span.

Comment: why using prev is wrong here? isn't tht .content is next of .card?

Comment: @jamieeason `.itemLink` is a child/descendant of `.card`. We don't even know what element is the previous element of `.card`. but it doesn't matter anyway.