# jQuery to find text from a <span> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab the text from a  element to do a google search.

The source code

```
<span><b>Likely domain</b>
: example.com</span>
```

I tried

```
  var search = $('span b').text( );
```

and that just grabs the `Likely domain` part but I need the `example.com` section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a value of a <span> using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921342/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-a-span-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the `b` selector:

```
var search = $('span').text( );
```

Comment: thanks that worked i just had to remove the likley domain part  var search = $('span').text( ).replace('Likely domain:',''); worked perfect .Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```
var search = $('span').text().split(': ').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x=$('span').text();
var arr=x.split(':');
alert(arr[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><b>Likely domain</b>
: example.com</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `b` selector because it will return only `text` which inside `b` tag

`$("span").text();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = $("span").html().split(":")[1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sd8tk81b/