# Update input value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input :

```
<form>
  <input class="total" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```

And div :

```
<div class="product">
  <figure>
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="product 1" />
    <!-- Hover -->
    <figcaption>
      <p>Add to input</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p class="descript">Description</p>
  <p class="price">99,00</p>
</div>
```

**Question:** How to increase input value by price in every click?

Now I increase only number of clicks.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cL494r31/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First init your total by 0 :

```
<input class="total" type="text" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
```

And every time you click get `total` value and add `product_price` value to it, see worked example bellow.

Hope this helps.

```js
    $(".product").click(function() {

        var product_price = parseFloat ( $('.price').text() );
        var total         = parseFloat ( $('.total').val() );

        if( !isNaN( total ) )
        {
            $(".total").val( parseFloat( total + product_price));
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input class="total" type="text" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</form>

<div class="product">
    <figure>
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="product 1" />
        <!-- Hover -->
        <figcaption>
          <p>Add to input</p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <p class="descript">Description</p>
      <p class="price">99,00</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt($('.price').html(), 10);`

Check this:[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/cL494r31/1/)

```
$(".product").click(function() {
    // pobieranie wartości
    sum += parseInt($('.price').text(), 10);

    // add to input value
    $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

Comment: Always use `radix` when using `parseInt` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: What if I have a few divs with different prices?

Comment: @ rylko we can answer the question with the help of available codes. The condition which you have told he has to handle by using the id attribute.

Comment: Why are you using `.html()` in this case?

Comment: .text() also fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921342/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-a-span-using-jquery

Comment: `.html()`  return HTML and `text()` return text, example if div contain `<b>99</b>` , the first will return `<b>99</b>` but the second will return `99`.

Comment: Oh. yes you are correct. but here the parse int will remove those unwanted tags. text() is the best approach then. thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
$(".product").click(function() {
    if(!$(".total").val()){
   $(".total").val((parseFloat($('.price').text())+1)); 
    }
    else{
          $(".total").val((parseFloat($(".total").val())+1)); 
    }  
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cL494r31/2/)