# How to get the value of span inside a td using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get the value inside the span class using Jquery?

```
<td class="date-data"> 
    <input type="text" id="start_2262016233000" class="form-control form-control-small make-small fieldEditable sampleValidation hasDatepicker"     style="display:none" value="26-Jan-2015" maxlength="10" name="$FO$i_submitSample.arrSampleStartDaTe">
    <span class="lblStartDt lblCurrentValue">26-Jan-2015</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a value of a <span> using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921342/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-a-span-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.date-data span').text();
```

It'd be better to add a *id*.

Comment: <td id="sample"> ?

Comment: then how to access it with id? $('.sample span').text();

Comment: Yes. `$('#sample span')`, but you can add a id to the `span`, right?

Comment: @NateNate you use `#` for id's. So `$('#sample span').text();`.

Answer (score 1):

`<td id="my-td">...</td>`

```
$('#my-td span').text();
```

It's better to supply id's.