# How to get the value with span text by using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to `jquery`. I designed form field input text with `span` text.

```
<div class="input-group" style="width:40%">
    <input type="text" name="emial" id= "emial" class="form-control" required="true"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```

i am trying get the value in jquery

```
var emial=$("#emial").val();
```

but i am getting only input text not with `@gamil.com`

Comment: @Pramod Patil: it's not duplicate please check care fully and read my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a value of a <span> using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921342/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-a-span-using-jquery)

Comment: @Amr Aly: it's not duplicate please check care fully and read my question

Comment: Nothing personal but what i really see that you are trying to get the text of span am i right?

Comment: Not only span,text box value with span.Combination here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the text content of `span` immediately after the element. Where use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method to get the `span` element and use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text) method to get the text content.

```
var $email = $("#emial");
var email = $email.val() + $email.next().text();
```

```js
$('#email').on('input', function() {
  var $email = $(this);
  var email = $email.val() + $email.next().text();
  console.log(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group" style="width:40%">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="true" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Span is not input tag . val() is used for input type tags only.

use it like:

```
var emial = $("#emial").val() + $("#emial").next("span").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a `span` element, use either `.text()` or `.html()`

```
var emial =$("#emial").val() + $("#emial").next("span").text();
```

```js
var emial=$("#emial").val() + $("#emial").next("span").text();
console.log(emial)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group" style="width:40%">
    <input type="text" name="emial" value="mail" id="emial" class="form-control" required="true"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#emial" ).html();
```

you will get the full result with html content

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .text or .html method for span and div

```
var email=$('.input-group-addon').text();
```

or

```
var email=$('.input-group-addon').html();
```

In place of .input-group-addon give Id to the span call the same function