# Get value of span with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

OK, so I am working on a web project with Spring boot and use Thymeleaf as templating engine and in one page I have the following:

```
[...]<span   th:switch="${cost.achitat}" class="pull-right">                                    
  <span th:case='true'  class="btn btn-xs btn-default" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" th:value="${cost.cost_id}"></span>
  </span> 
  <span th:case='false' class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </span> 
</span>[...]
```

(the "achitat" parameter of the object is boolean and I have a th:each in a higher div, and if i set the text with th:text it displays correctly on my page, so the value is being transmited)

I am trying to get the value of the span inside the **true** case with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove').click(function(){
    var t = $(this).val();
    alert(t);
});});
```

But the alert is always empty. I know that this question has been asked before in some form or another, but I could not find a solution and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: `span` element don't have a value.  You can get their inner text with `text()` or their inner html with `html()`

Comment: well I did not know that, thank you!

Comment: Here is link for your requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921342/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-a-span-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that only input has a value. Others you must use data attribute.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" th:attr="data-value=${cost.cost_id}"></span>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove').click(function(){
        var t = $(this).data('value'); // if int the use parseInt() function;
        var t = paerseInt($(this).data('value'));
        alert(t);
    });});
```

Comment: Thank You, works almost perfectly, just one modification                 
`<span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" th:attr="data-value=${cost.cost_id}" >` just adding data-value was not working

Comment: Yes. It's because you are using template.. :)