# jQuery: Change div text on click, works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
$(".yearly-package").click(function() {
  $(".electro-price")
    .find(".woocommerce-Price-amount")
    .text(function() {
      var yearprice = $("#year_price").text();
      return $(this)
        .text()
        .replace("99.00", yearprice);
    });
});

$(".halfyear-package").click(function() {
  $(".electro-price")
    .find(".woocommerce-Price-amount")
    .text(function() {
      var halfyearprice = $("#halfyear_price").text();
      return $(this)
        .text()
        .replace("99.00", halfyearprice);
    });
});

$(".single-package").click(function() {
  $(".electro-price")
    .find(".woocommerce-Price-amount")
    .text(function() {
      var oneprice = $("#one_price").text();
      return $(this)
        .text()
        .replace("99.00", oneprice);
    });
});
```

When div is clicked, the price will change. However, if I click again on a different button - the price will not change again.

What's wrong? Why will it work on the first click only?

This the html

```
<div class="ps-package single-package first-pack" data-val="1">
<div class="ps-name">Single Package</div>
</div>

<span class="electro-price"><ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>99.00</span></ins> <del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>150.00</span></del></span>
```

Comment: put html (all code) here.

Comment: add your code in executable format

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, Updated HTML code

Comment: @Yarin you are missing some html,  Can't find any element with the id `one_price`

Comment: Your HTML is incomplete.  Try creating a Stack Overflow snippet that demonstrates the problem.   You're replacing the whole of `.woocommerce-Price-amount` with `.text()` but that span has *multiple* other elements inside, not just text.  If your `#input` is inside there (it's not in your sample, but it's not anywhere in your sample) then it will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

The replace( arg1, arg2 ) function is look for arg1 in your text for replace by arg2.

It's working in the first case because arg1 = "99.00" and you replace it by arg2 ("44.00" for example). In the second case you are looking with arg1 = "99.00" or you have change it by arg2 ("44.00"). So it can't found arg1 as "99.00" because you have "44.00" in your text now, you have to change "99.00" by the value you replace it on first case.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Do you know how I can archive this? I mean making '99' act as a variable to make all cases work..

Comment: You can simply get the current value of this htmlelement with a jquery selector, take look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921342/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-a-span-using-jquery